# Implement O(n) algorithm for determining if a string has all unique characters?

Tags: c++

Here I have O(n^2) algorithm implemented in C++ function to determine if a string have all unique characters.

```
bool IsUnique2(char *str)
{
    char instr[256];
    strcpy(instr,str);
    bool repeat = false;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<strlen(instr); i++)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=i+1; j<strlen(instr); j++)
        {
            if(instr[i]==instr[j])
            {repeat = true; break;}
        }
        if(repeat) break;
    }

    return !repeat;
}
```

This algorithm checks every char of the string with other char of the string in order to find if they are repeated.
This approach have time complexity of O(n^2) with no space complexity. Can someone suggest an algorithm implementation of time complexity O(n) ?

Comment: Use a lookup table to save the count of each character.  If you're trying to set one to a value greater than 1 you know you have a dupe.

Comment: "No space complexity"?

Comment: Is this just a question to build up rep?

Comment: You can try a Binary search tree which gives you Order O(n log n). So you will be comparing your current element with half of the list for each iteration.

Comment: If `strlen(str) >= 256`, then there must be at least one duplicate. So you should only need to sort and search the first 255 characters, if present. I believe that makes it a O(1) algorithm, and not O(n) because the bounding constant *c* is `255 * lg(255)` or 2048. I could be wrong, though. Its been a few years since I had my algorithm analysis class.

Comment: @jww: 256 => `size_t(CHAR_MAX)-size_t(CHAR_MIN)`. Ignoring that, sorting 255 chars is still a one-off error. The first duplicate could be the 256'th character.

Comment: @Subodh: You'd better check `strlen(str)<256` before doing that `strcpy`. Also, dump that `repeat` variable and just call `return false;` when you detect a duplicate.

Comment: @MSalters - I'm not sure what the `size_t(CHAR_MAX)-size_t(CHAR_MIN)` means. Characters can be 0 - 255, which is 256 possible characters less 1 for NULL. And I don't believe one-off's matter for BigO. It just increases the constant *c*.

Comment: @jww: Your assumptions about valid `char` range are incorrect. In particular, you're assuming that `CHAR_MIN` is always defined as 0 and `CHAR_MAX` is always defined as 255. The standard does not mandate that at all. In particular, a common value for `CHAR_MIN` is -128, and for `CHAR_MAX` +127, but 0/65535 is also legal. As for the one-off, my bad. I misread your `>= 256` as `>256`.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks. But the poster is clearly using an 8-bit character, not a wide character: `char instr[256];`. I doubt he's on a PDP-12.

Comment: @jww: "8 bit" is the same assumption; we have a `CHAR_BIT` macro because you shouldn't assume that either. Initial code is of course incorrect, for more reasons than just that (strcpy of random string into fixed buffer!)

Answer (score 6):

You could keep an `unordered_set<char>` of characters that you've already seen, and bail out if the character you're at is already in the set. Because access to the set is amortized constant time, your algorithm will run in O(n).

Instead of a set, you could also use an array of `bool`, because a `char` typically has a very small range (0-255).

Comment: All of Unicode is only 113000 characters. Not too difficult to make a bit map for it.

Comment: Whether that's a feasible number depends on your platform. Also, I don't think all these codepoints are contiguous, so you'd need to skip unused parts when mapping this into your bitmap. Moreover, Unicode is regularly extended, breaking your code. In theory, all 32-bit values could be used. Long story short: for Unicode, I'd _definitely_ go with an `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 4):

The following has a time complexity of `O(N)`:
It counts each character and stop once character is not unique.

```
bool IsUnique(const char *str)
{
    char counts[256] = {0};

    for (; *str != '\0'; ++str) {
        const unsigned char c = *str;
        ++counts[c];
        if (counts[c] > 1) {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't see that you are incrementing the pointer anywhere, so as it stands it would return false every time. And just for the sake of it: a one liner version of your implementation: `bool iu(const char*s){for(char c[256]={};*s;)if(c[*s++]++)return 0;return 1;}`

Comment: A few seconds late. :)